# Early returns in React sub render function: return null, [], or React.Fragment?

Tags: reactjs, react-fragment

Let's say I have a simple component that may or may not render a Counter.

What's the best practice in React to express a blocked code path? Should it return `null`, `[]`, or a `Fragment`?

```
class App extends Component {
  renderCounter() {
    if (!this.props.shouldRenderCounter) {
      // // which should I return?
      // return; 
      // return null; 
      // return []; 
      // return <React.Fragment />; 
    }
    return <Counter />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderCounter()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I think `null` is the clearest, but I can imagine it causing problems if the context around the return function expects a component. `[]` and `Fragment` both seem like fine options to me, except Fragment is a little easier to read. What's the difference?

Comment: I would just go with null, but this seems to be mostly opinion based.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Returning `null` is [recommended by the React team](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering):

> In rare cases you might want a component to hide itself even though it was rendered by another component. To do this return null instead of its render output.

Comment: Could anyone provide with the reasoning behind it? I find it a bit anti intuitive that you have a parent rendering a child, and the child then deciding not to render itself.

Comment: @RTYX It can be useful in situations where you need the logic of whether a component renders to live inside the component itself. As the quote in my answer says; this is a "rare case", and in general it is better to prevent the component from rendering at all than to return `null`.

Comment: Sure, I understand that reason, I just have a hard time imagining a situation in which that logic cannot exist in the parent element but it can exist in the child, and if it can exist in either of them, I wonder why would I put it in the child.

Comment: I think a common example might be a component which fetches remote data inside a call to `useEffect` as soon as it renders for the first time, but while the fetch is pending it returns `null` because it's not ready to display anything.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create an extra function for it.

This will do the job:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.shouldRenderCounter && <Counter />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My case is a contrived example. The actual code can’t be one-lined as easily

Comment: Yes. This doesn't answer the question. Came here for same reason as OP.

Comment: In defense of this answer: I think the implied point is that you shouldn't be calling a separate method on your Component to render *part* of that Component. That "subsection" of the Component would likely work better as an actual, separate Component with its own `render()` method.

So in OP's example, it would actually be cleaner to extract the logic from `renderCounter()` into its own Component. Then, decide whether to include that Component as part of the caller's `render()` method (similar to the example in this answer).